# .NET custom dependencies (no nuget)

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, dependencies, nuget

So, I'm having trouble adding a git project to my `net Core` solution, and after spending hours trying to figure this out and being uncapable of finding a solution online, I decided to ask here.

I have a forked github repo ([link](https://github.com/bootzin/ImGui.NET)) in which I modified some files to suit my needs, but I simply can't seem to get it to work with my current project.

The problem I'm having is that normally, when I want a package for a .NET project, I usually simply go to nuget and fetch the necessary dependencies. This is usually very simple and straight forward. But now that I have these modified files, I'm unsure on how to proceed.

I have tried adding it as a submodule, but after I built the project, I got an exception saying that the dll could not be found. 
Then I've tried adding the dll itself as a reference, but the ImGui.dll depends on a C dll which couldn't be found then (nor added to the project).
Finally, I've tried adding the csproj as a project of my solution, but that didn't work either

Do you know what am I doing wrong here? Am I missing a key piece or is it just something obvious I'm not seeing? It can't be this hard to get it to work

Comment: Copy the C Dlls to the output directory of your main project (`bin`, typically). You can setup a custom post-build action to deploy the necessary Dlls automatically on successful builds.

Comment: `I have these modified files, I'm unsure on how to proceed.` hi, what's the content about the changes? I simply clone the repo and build will always succeed. Please let us know more about the changes, and what;s the error message you got. It could be better that you can share some steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the look of it, that repository produces a DLL (output type Class Library). So modify it to your liking, and use the sample program build (ImGui.NET.SampleProgram) to test your changes. Once you're happy, build the DLL project (ImGui.NET) and use the resulting DLL as a Reference in your own app.

In Visual Studio:

`Solution Explorer>YourApp>References>Right Click>Add Reference...>Locate your DLL`

This means you should also keep track of your modifications to the ImGui.NET project itself, since you may/will be required to maintain this in the future.

Hope this gets you started -- update your question with more specific issues once you're underway.

**Edit:**

Like @CoolBots mentions, I probably misread your question. Seems like the build depends on `cimgui.dll`, which you can hotlink from the ImGui repo along with your custom DLL. In fact, the demo app is using `cimgui.dll`, `cimgui.dylib` and `cimgui.so`. Regardless of linking method, you want the files to **copy** into your build folder. I don't believe subfolder */bin* is necessary.

You can find all the cimgui dependencies for various operating systems in the `~/ImGui.NET/deps/cimgui` folder.

The demo also utilizes NuGet packages `Velrid` and `Velrid.StartupUtilities`.

Depending on your own codebase, you may or may not require these NuGet packages along with the aforementioned class library.

Comment: The OP specified: "Then I've tried adding the dll itself as a reference, but the ImGui.dll depends on a C dll which couldn't be found then (nor added to the project)." - which suggests they know how to do the part you're describing. Perhaps you can address the C library portion, to improve your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I've finally managed to get this right, I ended up including the dll as a reference and doing some code in the csproj to manually copy the C dlls from a dependencies folder into my project, also taking care of platform specifics. This also avoided any unwanted dependencies from the demo project, thanks a lot!